# NSMutableArray calling html file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to change one of the tutorials Sam's teach yourself iOS in 24 hours. In this example, a tableview is loaded with an NSMutableArray that defines various external URLs. How can I modify this bit of the code to call html files (bundled) instead of the external URLs? Thanks in advance.
The code is like so:

```
- (void)createFlowerData {

NSMutableArray *redFlowers;
NSMutableArray *blueFlowers;

_flowerSections=@[@"Red Flowers",@"Blue Flowers"];

redFlowers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
blueFlowers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[redFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Poppy",
@"picture":@"Poppy.png",
@"url":@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppy"}];
[redFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Tulip",
@"picture":@"Tulip.png",
@"url":@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulip"}];
[redFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Gerbera",
@"picture":@"Gerbera.png",
@"url":@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerbera"}];
[redFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Peony",
@"picture":@"Peony.png",
@"url":@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peony"}];
[redFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Rose",
@"picture":@"Rose.png",
@"url":@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose"}];
[redFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Hollyhock",
@"picture":@"Hollyhock.png",
@"url":@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollyhock"}];
[redFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Straw Flower",
@"picture":@"Strawflower.png",
@"url":@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peony"}];
[blueFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Hyacinth",
@"picture":@"Hyacinth.png",
@"url":@"http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyacinth_(flower)"}];
[blueFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Hydrangea",
@"picture":@"Hydrangea.png",
@"url":@"http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrangea"}];
[blueFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Sea Holly",
@"picture":@"Sea Holly.png",
@"url":@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_holly"}];
[blueFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Grape Hyacinth",
@"picture":@"Grape Hyacinth.png",
@"url":@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grape_hyacinth"}];
[blueFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Phlox",
@"picture":@"Phlox.png",
@"url":@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlox"}];
[blueFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Pin Cushion Flower",
@"picture":@"Pincushion flower.png",
@"url":@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scabious"}];
[blueFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Iris",
@"picture":@"Iris.png",
@"url":@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_(plant)"}];

_flowerData=@[redFlowers,blueFlowers];

}
```

I tried the following:

```
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"];
```

and then changing:

```
[redFlowers addObject:@{@"name":@"Poppy",
@"picture":@"Poppy.png",
@"url":htmlpath}];
```

When i tap in a row,  I get the new view is pushed in, but my html file is not showing.
Looking at the detail view code:

```
@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        NSURL *detailURL;
        detailURL=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.detailItem[@"url"]];
        [self.detailWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:detailURL]];
        self.navigationItem.title = self.detailItem[@"name"];
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.hidden=YES;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

What am I missing? It looks like it should work!

Comment: How do you "call" a file?

Comment: (I think it's going to take more than 24 hours.)

Comment: i updated the question Hot Licks.... Thanks

Comment: First thing to check:  Is "htmlpath" non-nil?

Comment: Second thing to check:  Do you spell it "htmlpath" or "htmlPath"?

Comment: honestly a fellow member sent me that earlier. and yes it will take more than 24 hours.... it's not my day job :)

Comment: BTW:  Nothing "calls" a file, and an array doesn't "call" anything.

Comment: htmlPath...maybe call is not the proper term.... but from your posts, I see that you smell what I'm steppin in :)
The way the array us set up, the tableview loads okay. Tapping on the modified cells pushes the detail view but the uiwebview is blank.....

Comment: I've also tried this:                           
    @"url":[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"]}];

Comment: First thing to do is to separate the problem into possible causes.  There are 3: 1) Generating the wrong (or nil) path string, 2) somehow "losing" a valid path string into/out of your array/dictionary stuff, and 3) somehow mucking up the actual file load.  Deciding which of the three is the problem is a simple debugging operation.  Do that and you've got a much smaller problem to solve.

Comment: Thank you I will attempt that.